# How to run a thread repeatedly after some interval

Tags: java, android, multithreading, scheduler

I want to run a thread (Which does some time consuming task in background and does NOT update UI) it just downloads some files form the internet and it is independent from the UI.

I want to run this thread repeatedly after some time interval.

How can i do this, I have thread something like below:

```
boolean mResult =false;

void onCreate()
{
    DownloadThread mDownloadThread = new DownloadThread();
    mDownloadThread.start();
}

class DownloadThread extends Thread implements Runnable
{
    public void run() 
    {
       // My download code 
       mResult  = result;
    }
}
```

Do i need to use `Handler` for implementing this?

Answer (score 22):

**Option 1:**

```
volatile boolean flag = true;

public void run() 
{
    while(flag)
    {    
       // Do your task
        try{
            Thread.Sleep(interval);
        } catch(Exception e){

        }

    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do your task
    }

}, 0, interval);
```

**Option 3:**

```
volatile boolean flag = true;

public void someMethod(){
     // Do your task
     try{
         Thread.Sleep(interval);
     } catch(Exception e){

     }
     if(flag)
        return;
     else
        someMethod();     
}
```

**Option 4:**

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
volatile boolean flag = true;

Class A implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        // Do your Task
    }
    if(!flag)
       handler.postDelayed(a, interval);
}

A a = new A();

handler.postDelayed(a);
```

There will be many more options. I never tried option 3 and 4. It just came to my mind and I wrote. If I were you I would use any of 1 or 2.

Answer (score 8):

Prefered choice is

```
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService
```

Newer and robust implementation, More here [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Comment: Best response so far, this should be accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 5):

I would use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) to achieve this. Try this:

```
void onCreate()
{
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Download your stuff
        }

    }, 0, 1000);
}
```

It starts immediately and the run-Method gets called every second.

Comment: it hangs the UI