# Android: Sceduling an AsynchTask class to run after one minute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, background-process

I have a problem , I am creating an application in which I want to play azan file in background whenever system matches with the azan time, azan should start playing whether the user is using any screen of app.

I have created an asynchTask class in Azan.java but I dont know where to run it so that it always run after one minute to check sysytem time with prayer Time, Whether it should run on welcome screen of app or any other. Need help

```
 class azanBack extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
 Azan azan= new Azan();
 Calendar now= Calendar.getInstance();
 int hour=now.get(Calendar.HOUR);
 int minute=now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
 int am_pm=now.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
 String temp_time= hour+":"+minute+am_pm;
    @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            azan.getTime();
            if(temp_time== azan.getPrayerTimes().get(0)){
                azan.fplayer.start();
            }else if(temp_time==azan.getPrayerTimes().get(2)){
                azan.zplayer.start();
            }else if(temp_time==azan.getPrayerTimes().get(3)){
                azan.aplayer.start();
            }else if(temp_time==azan.getPrayerTimes().get(5)){
                azan.mplayer.start();
            }else if(temp_time==azan.getPrayerTimes().get(6)){
                azan.iplayer.start();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531950/how-to-execute-async-task-repeatedly-after-fixed-time-intervals

Comment: I know this method , but I am asking where to put that code that will execute this asynchTask , whether it should be on welcome screen? or splash screen

Comment: for other solutions..see here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406240/how-to-run-a-thread-repeatedly-after-some-interval

Comment: where you want to execute asyntask..?

Comment: mean jo kaam repeatedly krna he wo kis screen me krna he..splash me ya welcome me..i thnk welcome me kro gi..splash to close ho jae gi ..

Comment: hmmm ok I try,is there any risk that it will block main thread?

Comment: i dont think ..because in the code asyntask is executing in a thread so it will not block the UI. if it will then you need a service for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use handler class to run code after some time of period

Here is code:

Define object of handler class

```
private static final long GET_DATA_INTERVAL = 1000;
Handler hand = new Handler();
```

put this code into your on create method of activity:

```
hand.postDelayed(run, GET_DATA_INTERVAL);
```

Add void run method into your main class

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

new azan().execute();
hand.postDelayed(run, GET_DATA_INTERVAL);


        };
```