# Android - how to run a piece of code every minute (synced with the device time)

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android App in which I need to run a piece of code every minute, when I say every minute I mean it should be synced with the device's time so every time the device time changes by one minute my code is executed.

So far I tried this but it is not working:

```
runnable=new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run(){

    long now=SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long next=now+(60000 - now % 60000);
    handler.postAtTime(this, next);

   }
 };
 runnable.run();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            int lastMinute;
            int currentMinute;
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                lastMinute = currentMinute;
                while (true)
                {
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    currentMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    if (currentMinute != lastMinute){
                        lastMinute = currentMinute;
                        Log.v("LOG", "your code here");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        thread.run();
```

Answer (score 8):

There are many other ways to do this:

**1) Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()**

**2) Thread.sleep(interval)**

**3) Alarm Manager**

In your way it will look like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() { 

    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        try{
            //do your code here
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        finally{
            //also call the same runnable to call it at regular interval
            handler.postDelayed(this, "*interval"); 
        }
    } 
}; 
handler.postDelayed(runnable, "*interval");
```

you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406240/how-to-run-a-thread-repeatedly-after-some-interval) for details

Comment: how can I set the interval to every minute of the device clock, not just delaying by 60 seconds.

Comment: just set the interval to 60000(1 minute) it will run with the system clock

Comment: No, setting the interval to 60000 will simply start counting from 60 to 1 no matter what is the actual seconds on the system clock.

Comment: I think you need to get current time and check when seconds = 0 then start your timer

Answer (score 1):

one can use handle and can give input as milliseconds and we can call the code for every minute and should not use any infinite loops while using two different layouts

```
         final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            handler.postDelayed(this, 60000);
        }
    };
    handler.post(run);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use handler if you want to initiate something every X seconds. Handler is good because you don't need extra thread to keep tracking when firing the event. Here is a Code:

```
private final static int INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 1; //1 minutes
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

Runnable mHandlerTask = new Runnable()
{
     @Override 
     public void run() {
          doSomething();
          mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, INTERVAL);
     }
};

void startRepeatingTask()
{
    mHandlerTask.run(); 
}

void stopRepeatingTask()
{
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mHandlerTask);
}
```

Comment: I already used `Handler`, my problem is that I can't synchronize between the minute that my code run and the actual minute on the device clock, what I want is simple, run my code every time the device clock changes by one minute.

Comment: ok, now i understand, will u use Date and time change listener for archive this?

Answer (score -1):

The modern method

```
new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {

            }, 30000);
```